# Eclipse Link strange behavior after re attaching entity tree

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have a standard JEE7 application using `Eclipse Link` as `JPA` engine and an Entity tree will all entities annotated with `CascadeType.ALL` in their `OneToMany` relationships. All Entities have `@GeneratedValue` ids from database sequences.

During a transaction I have fetched a managed instance of an Entity tree, then I detach the root then set null to all `@Id` fields and `@Version` fields of the tree and merge the root Entity.

As I expect all managed Entities in the tree, except from two, have new Ids. The problem is that 2 entities of different type retain the null in their id fields and when committing I'm getting the following Exception:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Null or zero primary key encountered in unit of work clone [EntityA [id=null, businessId=17EN000000000083]], primary key [null]
```

I tried several changes in equals and hashCode methods in that EntityA mainly to avoid regarding two entities equals if their ids are null in both of them, but nothing happened. The behavior is not deterministic, during debugging sometimes the id was generated but usually is null.

Could anyone give a hint for the problem.

--EDIT

When we used `FetchType.EAGER` instead of `FetchType.LAZY` in problematic relationship, the `merge` created the ids as expected. Could anyone explain why this happens?

Comment: If you are trying to clone an existing tree, why not implement a clone method to create a new copy? Otherwise, what happens if you merge (or better yet, persist) the problem entity directly rather than through the graph?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new version of the entity tree. After detaching and setting null the ids I increase the version number of each entity. If I use clone I have to manually clone all entities of the tree, with cascade detaching I only detach the root entity and merge it back after changes. It seems to me that something related to identity maps of eclipse link cause the problem. If a isolate the problematic entity create a new one and persist it everything works fine. Does anyone knows how eclipse link entity manager checks during merging if the entity already exist in cache?

Comment: you are creating it wrong in an environment where EclipseLink is using change tracking. You need to make a copy of your entities, not just reuse an existing one and change its PK.  Try it, or try persisting the object directly as I suggested.  The behaviour you are seeing is easily explainable if your lazy relationship wasn't fetched before your 'detachment' - you didn't explain how you are detaching these entities.  EclipseLink allows accessing lazy relationships as long as the context they were read from is still available, so accessing that relationship is reading in managed entities.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are serializing your entity, it is not really detached. EclipseLink has functionality that allows fetching lazy relationships as long as the context is still available, which pretty much means until the EntityManagerFactory is closed or the entity is serialized.  So if you 'detach' your entity and traverse a lazy, unfetched relationship, the referenced entities will be read in from the EntityManager that performed the initial read, and be managed.

Regardless of that, since change tracking an other artifacts get woven into your entities, you are better off copying your entity if you wish to persist the data with a new identity.