# How entity manager uses hashcode and equals in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I have a standard `JEE` application with `JPA`. While merging previously detached entities does entity manager uses `equals` or `hashcode` to find if the object I merge is already managed? Generally when entity manager uses `hashcode` or `equals`? Is this affected by the JPA engine I use, for example `Hibernate` or `Eclipse Link`?

Comment: An EntityManager does NOT use hashCode/equals at all. They are used by java.util.Collection classes.

Comment: How entity manager finds during merging if an entity is already managed?

Comment: Collection.contains? An EntityManager knows what objects it is managing

Comment: and as far as dirty checking, those that use bytecode enhancement don't need to go off and check each field for whether it is changed, since the bytecode stores that information when a field is changed

Comment: This question seems like you are fishing for a solution to the problem you are experiencing in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091598/eclipse-link-strange-behavior-after-re-attaching-entity-tree?noredirect=1#comment81211743_47091598 .  If you think your equality/hashcode implementation is contributing to the error, it should be much easier and effective for you just to remove those methods and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is implementation dependent, but using your Entity hashcode or equals methods would not be all that reliable for any JPA mechanism.  EclipseLink does not use your equals or hashcode implementation to perform lookups or comparisons - it will use the System.identityHashCode when a hashcode is need.

An incorrect or inefficient hashcode and equality method will still have adverse affects on your application though, especially in mappings that use collection types. I'd recommend you not override them without some great need.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate the state of an entity Hibernate uses [Dirty checking](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/).

With dirty checking

> By default Hibernate checks all managed entity properties. Every time an entity is loaded, Hibernate makes an additional copy of all entity **property values**. At flush time, every managed entity property is matched against the loading-time snapshot value.

The dirty checking is performed by checking all **property values** saved at loading time.

There is no relation of `equals` and `hashcode` with how `entitymanager` works internally in Hibernate.